# WP7 Service Call in background worker C#

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

I am developing an wp7 app. In that i consume WCF service to get data on application start. After getting data i need to store it in ISO Store. Service call is happened in `DoWork` event of  `BackGroundWorker`. To my knowledge only async call is possible with WCF in windows phone 7. I am getting data on `Completed` event of service call. But the `Background worker completed` event is occurring before `Completed` event of service. I need to update some online status of user after getting data from service call.

What is the best practice to update my status. Is it good to do in `Completed` event of service call? or is there any way to update the status in `Background worker completed` event.

Here is my code

```
    private void StartLoadingData(bool status)
    {

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(status);
    }


    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CurrentUser))
        {
           ServiceReferenceClient cl = new ServiceReferenceClient() ;
            cl.ChangeUserStatusCompleted += new EventHandler<ChangeUserStatusCompletedEventArgs>(cl_ChangeUserStatusCompleted);
            cl.ChangeUserStatusAsync(this.CurrentUser, true);               
            e.Result = true;
        }           

    }

    private void cl_ChangeUserStatusCompleted(object sender, ChangeUserStatusCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // here i will get my result to process next step
    }
   private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      // result obtained from service need here
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a backgroundworker for an asynchronous call? If you need it to execute the callback in the UI thread, you can use the dispatcher instead:

```
private void StartLoadingData(bool status)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CurrentUser))
    {
       ServiceReferenceClient cl = new ServiceReferenceClient() ;
       cl.ChangeUserStatusCompleted += new EventHandler<ChangeUserStatusCompletedEventArgs>(cl_ChangeUserStatusCompleted);
       cl.ChangeUserStatusAsync(this.CurrentUser, true);               
    }  
}

private void cl_ChangeUserStatusCompleted(object sender, ChangeUserStatusCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
    {
        // Update the UI here
    });
}
```

Comment: I have to make some 4 service calls on startup for different purpose. So i preferred backgroundworker

Comment: @Satheesh My point is that using a background worker won't serve any purpose, since the call is asynchronous. You could use a ManualResetEvent to prevent the DoWork method from exiting until the asynchronous call ends, but that's a complete waste of resources

Comment: @Satheesh Also, even when using a background worker, why do you absolutely want to do the processing in the `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` method? Just use `cl_ChangeUserStatusCompleted` and it'll work fine